# Пунктуация в объявлениях.

Tags: пунктуация

Читаю объявления на остановках и в газетах, и задаюсь вопросом: как расставлены запятые или скобки ? Везде по разному: где невпопад, где вообще без них. А как правильно? Я увидел такой пример вообще без запятых:

1. В магазин сотовых телефонов(,) в Александровке(,) требуется продавец. (Мне кажется, что название населенного пункта идет как уточнение и должно быть выделено запятыми или лучше скобками?).
2. Мужчина(,) 40 лет, без вредных привычек, с высшим строительным образованием(,) ищет работу по специальности.  (Как здесь быть с запятыми или характеристики заключить в скобки ?)

Answer (score 4):

1) "В магазин сотовых телефонов в Александровке требуется продавец".

Здесь "в Александровке" является несогласованным определением для "магазина", обозначает основной, отличительный признак, а не уточняющий.

2) "Мужчина 40 лет, без вредных привычек, с высшим строительным образованием,  ищет работу по специальности".

Мужчина 40 лет - здесь автор считает свой возраст  важным, отличительным признаком, а остальные -  уточняющими.

Другой вариант - все признаки можно считать однородными: "Мужчина 40 лет, без вредных привычек, с высшим строительным образованием ищет работу по специальности".

Поэтому делаем вывод: разное оформление передает разне оттенки смысла.

Comment: Vera, спасибо большое за ответ ! Помогите мне еще с запятыми в таком примере: Женщина  лет сорока, брюнетка, в красивом платье, подошла ко мне и спросила... (Так правильно?).

Comment: Да, это единственно правильный вариант. Сначала мы определяем слово с неясным значением (женщина), а потом следуют уточняющие признаки